# xcode 4 mac app icon

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

How can I change mac app icon, so I could see it in dockbar & when I share it as application - in Finder ?

Any attempts to change icon in Xcode failed - the icon of application stay the same (default). I'm trying to share app as application, but in finder icon the same - default.

I drag icon file from Icon Composer to target's image. Check Info.plist - icon file points to correct location.

What's may be wrong ?

Comment: This may answer your questions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659628/application-icon-showing-default-not-iconset/12659701#12659701

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I drag icon file from Icon Composer to target's image. Check Info.plist - icon file points to correct location.

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing here - I might be misinterpreting you - but you want to build the icon in Icon Composer, save that as an .icns file, add it *to your project* (put it in a Supporting files group along with your app's info.plist and .strings files). This is because the icon has to be in the project in order to be copied into the app's bundle.

Then (1) click on your project, (2) then your target, look at the summary tab and (3) drag the icon *from your project* to the App Icon image well.

[image: Project window]

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in file extension. After using Icom composer, you should save file as .icns, no need for convertion to icon.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for it (i first created the 'Icon File' attribute manually in the plist and it worked also)