# Application Icon Showing Default, not IconSet

Tags: xcode, macos, icons

I have an app with two targets just about ready to ship but I still see the default app icon with the paper, pencil, etc. on the dock and in the main window when I select the app under Products.

I have an icon.iconset folder with 16, 32, 128, 256, 512, and 1024, all following the icon_XxX and icon_XxX@2x naming; under Products in XCode I see my 16x16 icon.  Under the targets' summary tab, show-in-finder shows that the iconset folder is indeed the app icon setting, as do the plist files (sans iconset extension).  All appears to be well, yet I'm still seeing the default icon in the doc.  I'm using 4.5 but I had the same problem in 4.4.1.  Icons are pngs.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: More: the Target Memmbership for the iconset folder is checked for both targets, yet when I examine the package contents in finder I am not seeing the iconset in the contents.  This is clearly the problem.

Comment: Worth noting for everyone experiencing this problem: previous responses refer to making a single icon.icns file.  In this instance I see that the build operation converts the iconset folder into an single object in the .app file that is called icon.icns.  It is actually a bundle of some kind and appears in preview as a set of ten icons.

Comment: See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337787/how-can-i-set-the-icon-for-a-mac-application-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.  Build was reporting successful operation in converting the iconset folder however examination of the logs showed that it was rejecting the folder because there is a maximum of ten files; I had every size needed for retina and that pushed the number to 13, so I removed the 64@2x and the two 1024x1024 files and now I see the right icon.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple Just add the icon assets and put up icon for all different size,and there are some online tools also available for app icon maker by using them you will definitely solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Thank you for providing an answer to this question. To improve this answer detail, how to add the icon assets and provide links to the online tools you suggest. For more help about writing a good answer see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer